# An excel macro to switch worksheets based on the values placed anywhere in a column range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a macro where it will switch from Sheet1 to Sheet2 when the word "Yes" is typed in any cell in column A. The closest I've come to getting this to work is with the code below that switches worksheets when "Yes" is typed in a specific cell.

```
Sub ifs()
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "Yes" Then
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Else
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not type "Yes" in that cell and create a hyperlink? Else you will have to use the worksheetchange event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I mentioned that you can create a hyperlink in Cell `A1` which will directly take you to Sheet2 but still if you want vba code then try this. This code will go into the sheet code area of `Sheet1`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1)) Is Nothing And _
    UCase(Target.Value) = "YES" Then _
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

**NOTE**: If you are interested in the Hyperlink approach then [THIS](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/create-a-hyperlink-HP005199516.aspx) is worth visiting. Checkout the section `Create a hyperlink to a specific location in a workbook`

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ifs()
If WorkSheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"),"Yes") > 0 Then
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
End If
End Sub
```